# Where is the saved dictionary located in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

I import the open office dictionary at Configure Texstudio->Language Checking->Default Language->Import Dictionary, and it sets "Spelling Dictionary Directories"="C:\Program Files\texstudio\dictionaries;[txs-settings-dir]/dictionaries".

I wonder where is the saved dictionary located and in which files.

Comment: `[txs-settings-dir]` is here: `%appdata%\texstudio`

Comment: Is it the location of the saved dictionary? Can it be changed?

Comment: Yes. For changing the path, you should rewrite the `[txs-settings-dir]/dictionaries` in "Spelling Dictionary Directories" setting, and then move `%appdata%\texstudio\dictionaries` there.

Comment: How do you move %appdata%\texstudio\dictionaries?

Comment: Run `explorer %appdata%\texstudio` commandline, and then you can see the `dictionaries` directory, which is moveable into your preferred directory.

Comment: @hair-splitter, thanks. Do you know which file in that folder contains the user-saved dictionary?

Comment: All of them. The default dictionaries are in `C:\Program Files\texstudio\dictionaries`

Comment: So I want to move the saved dictionary to another computer, I just copy everything in %appdata%\texstudio to the same location of another computer, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important to know is the location of "texstudio.ini" in my Ubuntu OS installation it was located here:
"/home/your_home_dir_name/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini".

The containing directory is equal to the value of the variable: "txs-settings-dir", e.g.:
"txs-settings-dir" = "/home/hans/.config/texstudio"